# Debian init.d script fails to sleep

Tags: linux, debian, init.d

This problem occurs on a Pogoplug E02 running Debian jessie.

At startup the network interface takes several seconds to come online.  A short delay is required after the "networking" script completes to ensure that ensuing network operations occur properly.

I wrote the following script and inserted it using update-rc.d.   The script inserted correctly and executes at boot time in proper sequence, after networking and before the network-dependent scripts which were modified to depend on netdelay

```
cat /etc/init.d/netdelay
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          netdelay
# Required-Start:    networking
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Delay 5s after eth0 up for Pogoplug
# Description:
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

./lib/init/vars.sh
./lib/lsb/init-functions

        log_action_msg "Pausing for eth0 to come online"
        /bin/sleep 5
        log_action_msg "Continuing"

exit 0
```

When the script executes at startup there is no delay.  I've used both sleep and /bin/sleep in the script but neither effect the desired delay.  Boot log showing this attached below.

```
Thu Jan  1 00:00:25 1970: Configuring network interfaces...done.
Thu Jan  1 00:00:25 1970: INIT: Entering runlevel: 2
Thu Jan  1 00:00:25 1970: Using makefile-style concurrent boot in runlevel 2.
Thu Jan  1 00:00:26 1970: Starting SASL Authentication Daemon: saslauthd.
Thu Jan  1 00:00:29 1970: Pausing for eth0 to come online.
Thu Jan  1 00:00:30 1970: Continuing.
Thu Jan  1 00:00:33 1970: ntpdate updating system time.
Wed Feb  1 05:33:40 2017: Starting enhanced syslogd: rsyslogd.
```

(The Pogoplug has no hardware clock and has no idea what time it is until ntpdate has run.)

Can someone see where the problem might be?

Comment: Isn't it because of this configuration `Using makefile-style concurrent boot in runlevel 2` ?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would affect the operation of sleep.  Every other executable called from the initscripts in /etc/init.d operates normally.  Could you expand on that?